# Postfix only delivering mail locally (instead of correct destination)

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot, g-suite, email-server

For whatever reason, postfix cannot send email to my google apps account. It says the message is sent, but I've confirmed with google apps support that the message isn't being received. (Thus it is not being blocked by their spam system. I've also added my server ip to the google apps white list and as a gateway just in case.)

Here are two logs from my mail server: one sends mail successfully to a test account and the other is a mail sent to my own gApps account which is failing. Take a look:

```
Feb 3 01:17:01 node postfix/smtp[25008]: 53FFC13EBA: to=<ana@sbtagent94.info>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.64.27]:25,delay=1.5, delays=0/0.01/0.27/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK1391408221 b6si3485695oem.31 - gsmtp)
```

Messages are delivered to the server aspmx.l.google.com with IP address 173.194.64.27

Here is a log for messages sent to my google apps addr:

```
Jan 27 20:56:46 node postfix/smtp[28904]: 4698113AFB: to=<samlevin@googleappsaddr.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.6, delays=1.3/0.01/0/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as C931C13E93)
Jan 27 20:56:46 node postfix/qmgr[23354]: 4698113AFB: removed
Jan 27 20:56:46 node postfix/pipe[28909]: C931C13E93: to=<samlevin@googleappsaddr.net>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
```

Message has a status of sent but in the first line doesn't specify to which server or IP address  and then informs that was delivered to dovecot (which is a local service running on the machine).

I can send mail fine from my postfix server to any other account, and I can receive e-mail just fine on my google apps account (googleappsaddr.net) from any other account. It's not the MX records on googleappsaddr.net as I've made sure those match the correct google-supplied MX entries.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your postfix delivers messages to samlevin@googleappsaddr.net to local dovecot (imap/pop server) via some email scanner.